# height of html with body and default margin on chrome

Tags: css, html

As you might know, Chrome has a default body margin of **`8px`**.

However, this poses an issue when I keep the margin on the body and set its height to **`100%`** (along with html at **`100%`**). It takes the height of html and places it after the top margin of **`8px`**, and ends with a bottom margin of **`8px`**. However the html size doesn't adapt to the 16 pixel difference (top 8 + bottom 8).

I'm thinking this has to do with how the document flow works, html having its size assigned before body does, but I do not have any clue how to fix issue.

The only way I thought I could fix this was to do  `calc()` notation on the html height attribute: `height: calc(100% + 16px)` but doesn't work. If you know why it doesn't I would like to be told.

code to replicate the issue:

CSS

```
html {
height: 100%;
background: rgb(42,69,66);
background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(73,94,8,1) 0%, rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%) no-repeat;
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

.divz {
    background-color: olive;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
   <div class="divz"></div>
</body>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd1hhz6q/) that replicates the issue. Notice at the bottom how theres a **`16px`** spacing between the end of the page and the end of html.

**EDIT:** I want the margin to stay on body.

**EDIT 2:** another thing I attempted is to set the `min-height: 100%` to the `html`, which does do what I want but setting `min-height: 100%` to `body` doesn't work if it is set to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I believe you want to keep the outer gradient I don't think setting `margin:0` and/or `padding:0` will help since it will remove the gradient border effect, but you can do it like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/2/) - *tested on* Chrome, Firefox *and* IE11

```
body { height:calc(100% - 16px); }
```

---

**UPDATED**

As stated in a comment the above, *as the other answer*, won't wrap content if the content exceeds the window height, to fix this we need a combination of **[`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc())** and [viewport unit **`vh`**](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport) <sup>(*)</sup> for the `.divz` div , as you can CSS need to have these lines:

```
html { min-height: 100%; }

body { height:100%; }

.divz { 
    padding:5px;
    /***
    full view height - 
          { (8px*2) default top and bottom padding + (5px*2) .divz top and bottom padding } 
    = 100vh - 26px
    ***/
    min-height:calc(100vh - 26px); 
}
```

[**JS Fiddle 2** - *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/19/) - *tested on* Chrome47, Firefox43 *and* IE11

***Full Code* :** -*updated*

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: rgb(42,69,66);
    background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(73,94,8,1) 0%, rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%) no-repeat;
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

.divz {
    background-color: olive;
    min-height:calc(100vh - 26px);
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divz">
  Candy canes dragée chocolate cake. Dragée cookie pastry. Sesame snaps macaroon croissant tootsie roll sesame snaps tootsie roll. Oat cake cotton candy wafer halvah tart chocolate cake croissant cookie. Sesame snaps carrot cake chupa chups pastry. Danish
  dragée bonbon jujubes dessert croissant bonbon jelly-o. Bear claw caramels topping. Candy candy candy jelly powder gummi bears. Jelly-o cotton candy fruitcake pastry apple pie toffee powder pudding. Dessert bonbon marshmallow donut. Gummi bears dessert
  cake cake gummies dragée soufflé. Candy canes muffin marshmallow carrot cake pastry sweet. Macaroon jelly-o icing biscuit lollipop bonbon chocolate bar jelly beans icing. Sweet biscuit liquorice cookie chocolate bar ice cream pudding cheesecake. Ice
  cream marzipan cheesecake lemon drops. Macaroon gummies carrot cake cheesecake fruitcake candy canes caramels chocolate bar. Fruitcake chocolate bar soufflé donut soufflé topping sweet muffin. Chocolate chocolate bar marzipan caramels dessert candy
  canes macaroon oat cake muffin. Cake cookie halvah jelly beans brownie candy chocolate cake macaroon. Wafer marzipan chocolate bar marzipan bear claw sugar plum. Sugar plum lemon drops fruitcake icing bear claw chocolate bar. Marshmallow sesame snaps
  sesame snaps pastry cake tootsie roll oat cake. Cake chocolate bar cake tart tart bonbon jujubes. Macaroon muffin dessert candy muffin ice cream toffee lollipop tart. Liquorice sugar plum lollipop. Sesame snaps fruitcake tart dessert tart wafer jelly
  beans tootsie roll. Cotton candy gummi bears cupcake cotton candy soufflé. Jelly beans topping soufflé pie wafer wafer brownie. Muffin icing halvah cookie candy sesame snaps cookie. Cotton candy tiramisu sweet bonbon tootsie roll powder tootsie roll
  bonbon fruitcake. Icing cookie tootsie roll. Pie donut marzipan. Sesame snaps pastry bonbon bonbon marshmallow caramels carrot cake bear claw. Fruitcake cotton candy gummi bears dragée liquorice toffee jelly. Candy caramels sweet roll. Bear claw tart
  macaroon cookie ice cream candy. Oat cake tootsie roll sesame snaps bear claw topping gummies. Apple pie jelly beans gummi bears cupcake cotton candy candy. Chocolate marshmallow sweet roll tiramisu candy gingerbread liquorice cupcake cake. Sweet roll
  cookie gummi bears. Croissant gummi bears halvah. Bear claw caramels icing cotton candy sweet oat cake cookie. Sweet roll donut jujubes sugar plum donut muffin pie. Macaroon tiramisu tootsie roll ice cream bear claw wafer cake pudding biscuit. Jelly-o
  gummi bears ice cream marshmallow sugar plum sugar plum caramels candy. Gummi bears chocolate bar cheesecake dessert. Toffee carrot cake candy marzipan carrot cake topping candy cake dragée. Tootsie roll chocolate cake powder tiramisu. Bear claw chocolate
  jelly croissant liquorice tootsie roll chocolate bar jelly-o lemon drops. Caramels biscuit pie apple pie marzipan tiramisu jelly-o wafer chocolate bar. Chupa chups jelly-o chocolate tiramisu. Pudding jelly cupcake. Halvah candy canes sesame snaps brownie
  chupa chups gummies candy bear claw. Sweet cupcake muffin sweet cake liquorice. Danish chocolate bar dragée macaroon cake brownie. Pastry liquorice tiramisu powder ice cream gummies pastry. Muffin jelly-o lemon drops lollipop candy canes sweet. Soufflé
  pudding ice cream sweet roll. Dessert biscuit dessert cake sweet gummies sesame snaps. Chupa chups carrot cake cupcake lemon drops bonbon cookie. Gummies sweet roll icing oat cake cookie muffin pudding. Tootsie roll toffee carrot cake donut icing sweet
  roll topping lollipop. Sugar plum fruitcake cupcake jelly croissant tiramisu cake donut. Wafer gummi bears sweet roll. Sesame snaps biscuit carrot cake wafer. Liquorice caramels dragée tootsie roll fruitcake. Jelly beans pudding toffee lollipop pudding
  oat cake sweet. Chocolate danish jelly-o bear claw.
</div>
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(*)</sup>  *Note that if you're going to target older browsers like* IE8 *and below and android < 4.3 as well then you need to have javascript code as fallback*.

Comment: This seems to work however this is not exactly what I want because If want to add elements to the page to a point that extends 100% - 16px, the body will want to wrap around it, causing it to extend and therefore, making the same issue.

However, thanks for this answer, It really does help with my project

Comment: `calc` is the last thing you wanna use, this has "bad practice" written all over the place. The performance loss is noticeable and you can implement the same thing using JavaScript, which is internally what CSS expressions are anyhow. http://robertnyman.com/2007/11/13/stop-using-poor-performance-css-expressions-use-javascript-instead/

Comment: @iMoses, that article is from 2007 (think IE6). Lots of progress in past 9 years. Nothing wrong with *calc*.

Comment: @iMoses I believe this is true for `expression()` function which is old and `calc()` is not as bad as `expression()`, also there're times when people require HTM / CSS Only solution, as yo ucan see there's no `javascript` tag in the OP

Comment: You are mistaken, the fact that you need the JavaScript engine to load before being able to render the CSS causes the page to display content with a greater lag. Nothing has changed with that for the last 20 years.

Comment: I think you're still talking about `expression()` , check this https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/ and search for "calc(" then try to search for "javascript" you'll see no existence of javascript, also from https://davidwalsh.name/css-calc ***`question:`** `is it faster than Java Script?` answer ***`Magne Andersson:`** `Since it is specifically made for these calculations, it should be, yes.`*

Comment: Sorry wrong link up there,  this is the correct one https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/

Comment: Also this function will *still work* even if you disable javascript in the browser http://i.imgur.com/wwb8mbm.png so how it could be relying on browser loading javascript first to execute it?

Comment: @Programgenesis, check the updated answer, it's fully functional including the J's issues :P

Answer (score 5):

```
html, body { margin: 0; }

body { padding: 8px; }

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd1hhz6q/8/)

Comment: Up voted, and @Programgenesis when I put huge text blocks to extend further than 100% both this answer and my answer had the same result, check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/9/ against this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/10/

Comment: Yes. I'm indeed having issues.

Comment: another way I thought of is setting min-height 100% to html and body. However min-height on body doesn't respond.

I never knew this would get so complex.

Comment: @Programgenesis, is this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/12/ what you're looking for?

Comment: No, Body should extend to the maximum by default. It doesn't do that if you remove your text.

Comment: Check this now https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nd1hhz6q/16/, totally remove the text or add couple lines of text, and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101357/discussion-between-program-genesis-and-mi-creativity).

Comment: for the J's you can use `padding:3px` for example but don't forget to subtract double the value -*one for top padding and other for bottom padding` so it becomes `min-height:calc(100vh - 22px);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to top of your css file, it will solve your problem

```
* {margin:0; padding:0}
```

Comment: Same as Micheal_B, I want to conserve the body padding and margin (There's no need for padding I believe since there is no default padding in user-agent-stylesheet)